# DocuSign Salesforce Connect Error: The UserID did not identify a User in the system

Tags: docusignapi

I'm getting this exact error when attempting to send a Conga merge document via Salesforce Docusign Connect:

Envelope could not be created.

Please contact DocuSign Support. Email to: service@docusign.com.

Error: System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: The UserID did not identify a User in the system. faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=missing in Web.Config

Note: The docusign email is different than the salesforce user's login email. But that shouldn't matter, right?

I have done the following in DocuSign:
- DocuSign Connect Configuration has Salesforce active and all checkboxes enabled 
- DocuSign API Username matches that of the user in salesforce
- DocuSign User is a member of DS Admin (and has all API rights checked by default)

And the following in the Docusign Admin (within Salesforce)
- The DocuSign account is properly logged in showing the correct credentials
- The user is an active user 
- The user appears, with the correct DocuSign API Username

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to debug this like this Salesforce StackExchange article describes to find out exactly the issue, rights, and / or permissions, configuration, etc.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158894/i-have-an-error-webservice-returned-a-soap-fault